# How do I print new line at the end of the for loop in python3 print function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print N-queen for every case for given input n. For this I have to write the condition explicitly for j=n-1 to get a new line after every 'n' columns.

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if j!=n-1:
            if j==a[i]-1:
                print('Q',end=' ')
            else:
                print('-',end=' ')
        else:
            if j==a[i]-1:
                print('Q')
            else:
                print('-')
```

Output:

```
#One case in n=5

- - Q - -
Q - - - -
- - - Q -
- Q - - -
- - - - Q
```

For not using condition explicitly I get the output in one line, which is obvious.

```
- - Q - - Q - - - - - - - Q - - Q - - - - - - - Q
```

Is there any way to implicitly write condition in print function in the place of end=' '?

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if j==a[i]-1:
            print('Q',(end=' ' if j!=n-1)) #this is not correct
        else:
            print('-',if j!=n-1: end=' ' ) #also not correct
```

I am using IDLE for python 3.4.2.

Comment: Did you try `print(<something>, end=(' ' if j!=n-1 else '\n'))`?

Comment: Oh sure that's what I missed. :) Thanks, it gives the correct result.

Comment: Python is amazing! :D

Comment: Do the same for 'Q' versus '-'. Let `<something>` = `Q' if j==a[i]-1 else '-'` and you just need one print statement

Answer (score 2):

Just print the newline at the end of the outer loop.

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
         ...
    print()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted implicit condition in print function in the place of end=' '.
Already got one way in the comment above by @vaultah.